# como fazer um update no banco utilizando checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

gostaria de saber como posso fazer um update com `checkbox`, com o sistema que eu desenvolvi eu consigo pegar normal todos os `checkbox` que serão alterados porem não consigo pegar o `id` dos respectivos como posso fazer isso? segue abaixo a parte do `html` e a do `php`

código HTML

```
       while($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $aux['id'];
        $nome = $aux['nome'];
        $img = $aux['imgp'];

        print"<div class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12\">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"$id\">
          <div class=\"hovereffect\">
            <span class=\"abcd\"></span>
              <img id=\"he\" class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"../images/imagens/galeria/big/$img\" alt=\"$nome\">
              <div class=\"overlay\">
                 <div class=\"btn-group\" data-toggle=\"buttons\">
                    <label class=\"btn btn-primary cke\">
                      <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"ck[]\" value=\"nao\" id=\"$id\"><i class=\"fa fa-heart\"></i>
                    </label>
                 </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>";

      }
```

código PHP

```
require "conexao.php";

    if(isset($_POST["final"])){


    foreach($_POST['ck'] as $ck){
        $check = $ck;
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE galeria SET favorito = '$check' WHERE id = '$id'")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }

    if($sql)
        echo "success";
    else
        echo "not success";
}
```

esse meu código ele ate funciona mas sempre faz o update no ultimo elemento, ex tenho 3 update seleciono o primeiro e o ultimo ele só ira alterar o ultimo queria que ele alterasse conforme o id do mesmo alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na parte que gera o `form`

```
  while($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $aux['id'];
    $nome = $aux['nome'];
    $img = $aux['imgp'];

    echo <<<END
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hovereffect">
        <span class="abcd"></span>
          <img id="he" class="img-responsive" src="../images/imagens/galeria/big/$img" alt="$nome">
          <div class="overlay">
             <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-primary cke">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="ck[]" value="$id" id="$id"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                </label>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
END;
  }
```

Na parte que insere, algo assim:

```
require "conexao.php";

if(isset($_POST["final"])){
  $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,
       "UPDATE galeria SET favorito = id IN( ".implode(',',$ck)." )"
     ) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```

Claro que idealmente você deve sanitizar os `id`s para evitar injection. Se quiser inverter o sentido dos checkboxes, basta trocar o `IN` por `NOT IN`.

Notar que eliminamos o loop, pois o `implode` vai juntar os IDs numa verificação só. O `WHERE` foi removido também, pois você vai receber somente os campos marcados, então vai usar o `IN` para determinar verdadeiro e falso. Atenção: só faça isso se o form contiver todos os campos, senão, vai precisar realmente do `WHERE` e mais o campo `HIDDEN`.

Pode ter algum erro bobo de sintaxe, o importante é entender as alterações e aproveitar as que forem úteis.

Comment: intao eu não posso passar o id no value no `checkbox` pois meus valores serão inseridos no campo favorito do banco que vai receber uma string se e sim ou nao por isso não posso passar o `id` no value do `checkbox`.

Comment: É o que o código acima faz. Ele armazena no campo favorito se os checkboxes estão marcados ou não, e é justo para isso que serve o `id` do campo. Se quiser string `sim` e `não` em vez de verdadeiro e falso, basta acrescentar um `IF( id IN..., 'sim', 'não' )` em torno da verificação do  `in` acima. Aliás, melhor seria ajustar a coluna no DB pra verdadeiro e falso do que mudar o código, não tem muita vantagem armazenar valor booleano em string no MySQL. Seja como fizer, colocar "sim" e "não" no value do checkbox definitivamente não é o caminho.